# How can I run an application in windowed mode

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I use to start an application in windowed mode by creating a shortcut and specifying the resolution in either `Target` or `Start in` field.

I think one of the parameters was `-h` and the other one was `-w` but I don't remember exactly how to do it anymore.

Now I have a different program that I would like to run in the same way but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: We need more detail. Like what program.

Comment: I dont understand why its not a real question?? It has a real answer doesnt it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just create a shortcut to the executable and add the parameter you need in the target field

[image]

Comment: The parameter you need is, of course, different from program to program; some programs may not have such a parameter at all.

Comment: you can search on google for app parameters (usually in games is -w)

Comment: if we only knew what app is...